# I cant understand this problem our teacher gave us

Tags: permutations, combinations

[image: Click this link to show the problem]

I tried to answer it with the counting method 2(cones)x 12(flavors) x 12 (toppings) = 288 Did i do the wrong method? What can i do to solve this problem?

Comment: The sentence is quite weird. Maybe you should ask your teacher to clarify exactly how many topings there are?

Comment: there are 12 toppings i think

Comment: Suppose that the possible sizes are : **small**, **medium** and **large**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is correct if there are 12 toppings. However the formulation is a bit werid. We can however figure it out without knowing how many toppings since it is an ABCD question. There are $2\times 12=24$ choises of cone and flavour (just like you calculated). Thus the number of total combinations is $24\times x$ where $x$ is the number of toppings. This means that the total number of combinations is divisible by $24$. Now the only answer, out of the given, which is divisible by 24 is $72$, thus this is the only feasible answer to the question.

Trivia: This implies that there are $72/24 =3$ toppings.